# How add Target Graphic for Button in Unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am creating a menu for the user. I have already added Canvas element. It has some text elements as it's child elements. One of text element's has Button component added.

I want this text-button change it's color when it is highlighted but I can't because Target Graphic is missing: "You must have a Graphic target in order to use color transition".

**How do I fix it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour , IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
    public Text text;
    public void OnPointerEnter (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        text.color = Color.white;
    }

    public void OnPointerExit (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        text.color = Color.black;
    }
}
```

Using the event system, you can have control of what to do and when. Simply add the interfaces and implement the methods. Don't forget the namespaces.

Comment: I think this approach is correct (although I didn't test it) answer to my _question_. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should go to the `menu` and search for the `GameObject` tab, there go to `UI` -> `Button`.

[image]

This way, Unity will create the `Button` `GameObject` with several childs, each one with a component (text, graphic, etc...), automatically.

Way faster than creating them by yourself and adding the components manually, and you won't be missing any component.

Comment: I have solved my issue by adding Button element (as you suggested) and not a Text element but also I had to make some changes to this Button to reach desirable  appearance level of this Button text. However you did not entirely answer my question. Still thanks.

Comment: nice answer BTW.  @snak in cases of duplicates, if you can find a *better duplicate* than one already given, that's even better - you get even more points.

Comment: Hey @JoeBlow , you are such a dumb person. Your knowledge in Unity is probably 0 so that's why you marked it as duplicate when it wasn't. It's not the same activating/deactivating a component than a gameobject. You should really start learning something useful instead of typing dumb comments 24/7. No, I don't seek points. Have a nice day, kid.

Comment: Hi Snak, you know what it is, I just quickly found anything that was vaguely like a duplicate.  The problem is it is a super-simple question with many, many duplicates of all varieties. (I just counted THIRTY FIVE questions on here about SetActive! here's one of a DOZEN! that describes the difference .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34908890/what-is-the-difference-between-getcomponentimage-enabled-and-setactive-fa )  Indeed, normally people just click "Too General" instead of bothering to find a duplicate. Nobody cares much about close reasons you know as long as there's a close vote

Comment: In cases of duplicates, if you can find a better duplicate than one already given, that's even better - you get even more points - awesome.  The main things is that we all help close "many times duplicated, easy questions" because otherwise the board will unfortunately become as useless as answers.unity3d .. then none of us can get any questions answered  :/  anyway sorry for the mixup there buddy Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Unity wants you to add an Image component to the object and put that in the Target Graphic field.  Just go to "add component" in the inspector, search image, and put that into Target Graphic.